# Scope of lists in Python 3

Tags: python, list, scope

This may be a very stupid question, but I'm a little uncertain as to why lists behave differently to other variables in Python 3, with regard to scope. In the following code...

```
foo = 1
bar = [1,2,3,4]

def baz():
    foo += 1
    bar[0]+=1
```

I understand why `foo += 1` throws an error with regard to `foo` being outside of local scope. Why doesn't `bar[0]+=1` throw the same error though?

Comment: because `bar[0]` is an expression which reads `bar`, which is allowed in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the code, you will get

```
 ....
     foo += 1
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

`foo += 1` is actually evaluated like this. `foo = foo + 1`. So, you are adding `1` to the value of `foo` and storing it in a variable `foo`. Since there is an assignment happening, Python assumes that `foo` is a local variable. But, if it is a local variable, in the expression `foo + 1`, what would be the value of `foo`? Python couldn't answer this question. That is why it throws that error.

But, when you do `bar[0] += 1`, Python evaluates it like this `bar[0] = bar[0] + 1`. Since, it already knows what `bar` is, and you are just trying to replace the first element in it, it allows it. In the last case, we were creating a new local variable called `foo` by doing `foo += 1`, but here, we are just altering the same object. So Python allows this.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `foo` points to an object (an integer). The variable `baz` points to an object (a list). If you try and reassign `baz` to another object you would get the error. But you're not, you're just calling a method on the list object, and anyone can do that.

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can't modify globals without the 'global' keyword. This is for clarity.

```
foo=1
def bar():
     global foo
     foo=2
bar()
#foo is now 2!
```

Since bar[0]+=foo modifies the an element of a list, not the value of the list variable itself, it is legal.